# php file and fopen functions not working

Tags: php, fopen, bots

I'm trying to learn about creating web bots and I'm working my way through a book called **Webbots, Spiders, and Screen Scrapers** by Michael Schrenk. In the book he gives example code for a basic bot that downloads a webpage. I have copied the code exactly as it is in the book (sans comments):

```
<? 
$target = "http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/hello_world.html";
$downloaded_page_array = file($target); 
for($xx=0; $xx<count($downloaded_page_array); $xx++) 
echo $downloaded_page_array[$xx]; 
?>
```

I put this code in a php file and uploaded to my site. When I navigate to it in the browser however, nothing happens. It just loads a blank page. No content.

Earlier I tried another snippet that the author provided, again, this one was copied EXACTLY from the book, only with this one I didn't really get a blank page, the page just tried to load until it eventually timed out. Never got the correct content back:

```
$target = "http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/hello_world.html";
$file_handle = fopen($target, "r");
while (!feof($file_handle))
echo fgets($file_handle, 4096);
fclose($file_handle);
```

I have checked the URL to make sure the file exists and it does. I have no idea why this wouldn't work. I've read through how to use the file(); and fopen(); functions in PHP but from what I can tell they are both being used correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Also, use `<?php` - often `<?` ('short_open_tag' in php.ini) is disabled.

Comment: See AbraCadaver advice. Try to replace `<?` with `<?php`: `<?` works only if explicitly configured. Your code works. If the errors persists, maybe your file_get_contents fails for some reasons, but following AbraCadaver advice, you'll see the error.

Comment: I have added the line of code that AbraCadaver provided, as well as switched from <? to <?php however I get the exact same results. :(

Comment: You call correctly the page? Can you try in commandline mode? Are you sure that above code is all the code you have in yr file? Maybe there is typo in remaining code, so produce a compile error: you can see compile errors only on apache error log or running script by commandline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing URLs via `fopen()` is a **bad idea**. It requires you to have `allow_url_fopen` enabled in your PHP config, which opens the door to a vast number of exploits (hosters disable it for a reason).

Try using [cURL functions](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead: they will give you much more flexibility and control. PHP documentation gives you some [great examples](http://au.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) to start with.

Answer (score 0):

First you should put `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to your script to enable displaying errors in your script as AbraCadaver mentioned in his comment.

A reason could be, that `allow_url_fopen` is disabled on your hosting.

> This option enables the URL-aware fopen wrappers that enable accessing URL object like files. Default wrappers are provided for the access of remote files using the ftp or http protocol, some extensions like zlib may register additional wrappers.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

You can check that via:

```
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));
```

Your script requires `true` to run correct.

If `allow_url_fopen` is not `true` or `1` you can try to use `file_get_contents()` to load a url.

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. I have taken your suggestions and added the lines of code to report the errors. This is what was returned:
string '' (length=0)

Comment: so it seems `allow_url_fopen` is not activated/allowed for security reaons. It seems you can't use `fopen()` to load a url. Please read my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not *`fgets($file_handle, 4096)`* but *`fread($file_handle, 4096)`* ;

```
$target = "http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/hello_world.html";
$file_handle = fopen($target, "r");
while (!feof($file_handle))
echo  fread($file_handle, 4096);
fclose($file_handle);
```

Then later if you want to create a new file from the *extracted* text :

```
  // extracting text operation
$target = "http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/hello_world.html";
$file_handle = fopen($target, "r");
$getText =  fread($file_handle, 4096);
fclose($file_handle);

// writing file operation
$writeHandle = fopen ("folder/text.txt","w"); // file will be created if not existed
$writeFile = fwrite($writeHandle,$getText );
fclose($writeHandle );
```